# In Python, how do I split a string after periods without affecting decimal numbers?

Tags: python-3.x, split

Suppose I have a string:

```
string1 = 'Pernod has reduced the debt it took on to fund the Seagram purchase to just 1.8bn euros, while Allied has improved the performance of its fast-food chains.Shares in UK drinks and food firm Allied Domecq have risen on speculation that it could be the target of a takeover by France's Pernod Ricard.'
```

I have a large amount of articles to work with in which the periods don't always have a space after them, but some do. How do I split the text into sentences without splitting up decimal numbers? TIA.

Comment: You can't really, you can only get close.  Just check to see if there is a number after the period. and hope no one is creating decimals without any percision

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using regular expressions, [re.split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), assuming no declarative sentence ends in a number and is followed by a sentence beginning with a number, without a space between the sentences (e.g., "This is my sentence ending in 1.2 is the start of my next sentence."; the first sentence ends in "1." and the next begins with "2").

That being said, split() alone will not be able to perform the desired action. It is also worth noting that, since apostrophes are more common than quotation marks, delimiting your string with quotation marks will likely be better. As it stands now, the very end of your sentence, "s Pernod Richard.", is not considered part of the string, and is therefore considered invalid syntax.

```
string1 = "Pernod has reduced the debt it took on to fund the Seagram purchase to just 1.8bn euros, while Allied has improved the performance of its fast-food chains.Shares in UK drinks and food firm Allied Domecq have risen on speculation that it could be the target of a takeover by France's Pernod Ricard."

sentences = re.split('[^0-9]["."][^0-9]', string1)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to protect the dots you don't want your text splitted at by replacing them with something else first, then re-replacing the placeholder back again after the split:

```
import re
# replace dots that have numbers around them with "[PROTECTED_DOT]"
string1_protected = re.sub(r"(\d)\.(\d)", r"\1[PROTECTED_DOT]\2", string1)  
# now split (and remove empty lines)
lines_protected = [line + "." for line in string1_protected.split(".") if line]   
# now re-replace all "[PROTECTED_DOT]"s
lines = [line.replace("[PROTECTED_DOT]", ".") for line in lines_protected]
```

The result:

```
In [1]: lines
Out[1]: ['Pernod has reduced the debt it took on to fund the Seagram purchase to just 1.8bn euros, while Allied has improved the performance of its fast-food chains.',
 "Shares in UK drinks and food firm Allied Domecq have risen on speculation that it could be the target of a takeover by France's Pernod Ricard."]
```